Cross-app information management system
I'm looking for an integrated solution for efficient organization of related information across different apps and formats (e.g., emails, bookmarks, files, notes, ...)
I find myself often in the following situation:
I need to access some information (whether a note, email, link, document, etc.) that I know I have but I can't remember where I saved it.

Did I save it as bookmark?
Did I download it and save it in a file?
Did it come in an email and I saved it in a mailbox folder?
Or did I create a note and save it in my notes app?

So here I have different apps involved all managing information in different format in the form of emails, bookmarks, files, notes, etc.
Currently, to maintain the semblance of organization I find myself recreating folder structures that look very similar across different apps, such as Firefox, the macOS Finder, Mail, ... But it's just super cumbersome and doesn't prevent me from the problem above that it is ambiguous where the information should live.
Does anyone know of a system that would allow me to keep all these different types of information organized across my system? Whether with some tagging scheme or with folders – ideally it would integrate with existing apps – but I'd also be happy to start from scratch as long as it's robust.
So, for instance, I'd like to have a tag or folder that says Research project 1 which I can use to collect any:

files associated with the project
bookmarks of links to relevant web pages
emails that someone sends me
notes with thoughts about it that I write on the go

I know, I could save bookmarks or emails as files and do all with Finder Tags – but that rips them out of their dedicated apps, i.e., the browser or the mail app – and is cumbersome as it duplicates the information. So ideally a system that somehow works with plugins across multiple apps.

Seems like you are looking for some sort of Document Management System. Correct me if I am wrong in this

How about a search system capable of indexing many types of apps/filetypes?

I don't think you'll find anything like that, especially for macOS. The closest  thing would be something like Google Keep, Evernote or a similar note taking app with plugins for browsers and some other apps like Tasker on the phone.

@KumarC yes and no, a management system for not only documents, but information of different kinds, like bookmarks, mails, notes ...

@ZZ can you elaborate? and I think even if I have a good search system or use tags systematically, that doesn't solve the issue of where the information should live ...

@Destroy666 Yeah, it looks like it may be difficult to find.  I wish there was some system that wasn't app/ecosystem-specific ... with plugins that would allow for cross-linking information ... so I can continue to use browser, mail app etc. but when information is saved (i.e., bookmarked) it is saved in such a way that it can be accessed from some central interface – I guess someone has to create it

What I have in mind is something like https://www.recoll.org/ which will natively search the info.

@jan A good DMS should address all your needs. I am using M365 and have a privilige o f using all the office related applications which does all the tasks that you have mentioned. But I am in a windows environment.
